# Use app scripts to pick email from sheets and send data as html table

Tags: google-apps-script

[sending mails as separate tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcw96.jpg),
[old data entering into the new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qadzz.jpg)
I am trying to pick email of the specific row and sending data to them as html table. i am getting an error of not find the recipient.

I am new guy to coding so any small help would be useful.
[image]
[image]

I am trying to pull the email id from the sheet and I person should get only one row data as separate mails

```js
function expiredjobs() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Oct-22");
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var numColu = sheet.getLastColumn(); // Number of colums to process 

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColu);
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  
  var bodyEmail = "Dear sir, <br/>  Kindly provide the recommendation for the below mentioned near miss, also provide the supporting document to close the incident. <br/> "  

  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1>"
  var colVal = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < 2; ++i) 
  {
      table = table + "<tr>"
       for (var colNo = 1; colNo <=11; colNo++) 
       {
        colVal = sheet.getRange(i , colNo).getDisplayValue();
        table = table + "<th>" + colVal + "</th>";
        }        
    table = table + "</tr>"
  }

  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; ++i)
  {
    var email = sheet.getRange(i,13).getValue().toString();
    var status = sheet.getRange(i,12).getValue().toString();
    var itemno = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValues().flat().filter(String).pop();
    Logger.log(email)
    Logger.log(status)  
    if(status === "Open")
    {
    Logger.log("1");
        table = table + "<tr>"
       for (var colNo = 1; colNo <=11; colNo++) 
       {
        colVal = sheet.getRange(i , colNo).getDisplayValue();
        table = table + "<td>" + colVal + "</td>";
        }        
    table = table + "</tr>"
    }
  }
  Logger.log("done");
  var le = table.length
  Logger.log(le);
  if (le > 200)
  {
    var subject =
        'ITS Ref No. ' + itemno + ' | ' +  'Report Status- OPEN';
    bodyEmail=bodyEmail + table
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,"",{htmlBody:bodyEmail});
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) in your code, « var email » is not changed, you don’t iterate

Comment: Yaa I tried changing it, it is not working

Comment: So update your code above to reflect the error you have

Comment: And now, in your data screenshot, I can see some line without emails. So it will be empty and crash, please add a condition as ```if (email == "") { return;}```

Comment: I didnt understand, i shouldnt iterate <<var email>>, but to get data from each row it should get iterated ?

Comment: Of course you have to iterate to get the right email. Now the error ```no recipient``` is probably because email is empty sometimes in Gsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've refactored your script a bit and it should only send emails to people with row status Open and has an email.

```
function expiredjobs() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Oct-22");
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); // Number of rows to process
  var numColu = sheet.getLastColumn(); // Number of colums to process 

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColu);
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  
  //use data values to get the text
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
    var email = data[i][12];
    var status =  data[i][11];
    var itemno =  data[i][0];
    Logger.log(email)
    Logger.log(status)
    Logger.log(itemno)
    
    if(status === "Open" && email != null)
    {
      var bodyEmail = "Dear sir, <br/>  Kindly provide the recommendation for the below mentioned near miss, also provide the supporting document to close the incident. <br/> "  
      var table = getEmailBody(sheet);
      table = table + "<tr>"
      for (var colNo = 0; colNo <=11; colNo++) 
      {
        colVal = data[i][colNo];
        table = table + "<td>" + colVal + "</td>";
      }        
      
      table = table + "</tr></table></body></html>"
      Logger.log(table)
      var subject =
        'ITS Ref No. ' + itemno + ' | ' +  'Report Status- OPEN';
      bodyEmail=bodyEmail + table
      Logger.log("sending email: " + email);
      MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,"",{htmlBody:bodyEmail});
    }
  }
}

function getEmailBody(sheet){
  
  var table = "<html><body><br><table border=1>"
  var colVal = "";

  table = table + "<tr>"
  for (var colNo = 1; colNo <=12; colNo++) 
  {
    colVal = sheet.getRange(1 , colNo).getDisplayValue();
    table = table + "<th>" + colVal + "</th>";
  }        
  table = table + "</tr>"
  return table;
}
```

Comment: thanks charles it is working but for the two email it is reading both the data and sending them as one table i am attaching a screen hot for your reference

Comment: I have updated the code to ensure the previous email table is not added in the second email. Each email will have headers. Also, I've fixed the HTML with closing tags.

Comment: i tired the new code also, to the second person it is sending 2 tables, old one and the new one to the third person three separate tables

Comment: i am adding a screenshot for reference

Comment: Fixed the issue. should be ok now. Basically, each email body needs to be re-initialised.

Comment: @MotamarriOmHarik does the code work for you?

Comment: its working perfectly thanks man, and how can make changes in the table width

Comment: You will have to add CSS in the HTML body, just like a website. I would appreciate it if you could accept this answer as it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clearer than comments. You error `Exception : Failed to send email : no recipient` is probably caused by empty mail column (in your Gsheet).

To correct :

```
//insert this before sendMail() fonction
if (email == "") {
  Logger.log('email empty');
  return;
}

MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,"",{htmlBody:bodyEmail});
```